# Pandas apply exponential decay + dataset to function

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have an activation function time series dataset comprised of instant events, meaning most of the time my dataset is zero but I have data points with a varying numeric value that corresponds to an event. I know this event causes some other effects that are proportional to the value at activation time and with the effect decaying exponentially.

I'd like to make a function in pandas that calculates the resulting, continuous dataset for my activation function, but I don't know which functions to apply.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad to be answerable here at the moment, it sounds like you have an analysis/data problem rather than a programming problem

Comment: Try stats.stackexchange.com for this question.